# The contracted Riemann tensor in vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, vacuum

When we say the background geometry satisfies Einstein’s equations in the vacuum does that mean that $R_{\mu\nu}=0$? I'm positive that not everything is zero in the equations since we have the Schwarzschild solution in vacuum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ in vacuum. A comparable statement in Newtonian gravity would be $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$. The sums of partial derivatives (in the Ricci tensor) can be zero even though each partial derivative on its own (in the curvature tensor) is not zero in cases such as Schwarzschild solution.